# NSFetchRequest with Predicate not returning objects

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

In my Delegate I specify the following method for retrieving an NSSet of NSManagedObjects:

```
- (NSSet *) entitiesForName : (NSString *)entityName matchingAttributes : (NSDictionary *)attributes {
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext: [NSThread isMainThread] ? managedObjectContext : bgManagedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity: entity];

NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[attributes enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([value class] == [NSString class]) {
        NSString *sValue = (NSString *)value;
        [subPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == '%@'", key, [sValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"]]];
    } else {
        [subPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", key, value]];
    }
}];
NSPredicate *matchAttributes = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
NSLog(@"matchPredicate: %@", [matchAttributes description]);
[fetch setPredicate: matchAttributes];

NSError *error;
NSSet *entities = [NSSet setWithArray: [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error]];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get %@ objects: %@", entityName, [error localizedDescription]);
    return nil;
}

return [entities count] > 0 ? entities : nil;
}
```

I then initiate this method using an Entity I know exists and matching an attribute I know has some of the same value (I checked the sqlite file):

```
[self entitiesForName:@"Lecture" matchingAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"attending"]]
```

The console outputs the following (showing the predicate):

```
2013-09-11 22:47:20.098 CoreDataApp[1442:907] matchPredicate: "attending" == 0
```

**Info on the NSObject Entity:**
 - property "attending" is a BOOL (translated to NSNumber in class)
 - There are many records in this table (Lecture entity), half with "attending" value 0 and other half 1
 - Using the method -entitiesForName above, it returns an empty set

**Other Info:**
I have another method defined to retrieve the same way, but without the predicate (retrieves all managedobjects) and this works going from the same table. I used this, and analysing the retrieved records from this also proves that some have "attending" 0 and some 1

**Question:**
Is there something wrong with my -entitiesForName method that would cause the set to come back empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `%@` for the key - you need to use `%K` for the key path.

For example

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, value]
```

You can find more info in the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

In your current case the key is being treated as a string